# Objects in class are nil when trying to access from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, properties

I have a View Controller class which contains a button property, and I need to change its enabled stated from a different class (Table View Controller). I'm also calling a method that's in that VC class. I can call the method just fine, but when I try to access the button property, it's nil. Actually all of its properties are nil. I must have something not set up quite right.

```
//ViewController.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *aButton;
- (IBAction)myButtonTapped;

//ViewController.m
//did not override setter or getter for aButton
- (IBAction)myButtonTapped {
     //code here
}

//Table VC.m
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *myVC;

- (ViewController *)myVC {
    if (!_myVC) _myVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    return _myVC;
}

- (void)userEnteredText:(NSNotification *)notification {
     [self.myVC myButtonTapped]; //runs method without issue
     self.myVC.aButton.enabled = YES; //does not occur since aButton is nil - myVC is not nil
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: I'm not passing data between VCs but rather just changing the button enabled state from a different class. Both VCs are actually on screen at the same time - the table VC is inside a container view which is inside the original VC.

Comment: Sorry, the dupe still applies -- view controller or not has nothing to do with it.  Study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study the information provided by @Hot Licks to understand how to keep references between your objects, but I can tell you that part of your problem is your getter method -

```
- (ViewController *)myVC {
    if (!_myVC) _myVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];   //  <-- This is a problem
    return _myVC;
}
```

If your _myVC variable is nil then your getter method allocates a *new* `ViewController` - so you won't get a reference to the existing `viewController`.  As you then call the plain `init` method for your new `viewController` none of its properties will be initialised - so you get nil for your button.

You don't need to write any code for a simple property like this - the default code that is created for you is all you need.  What you do need to do is set the `myVC` property from your current `viewController` instance. So somewhere in your `viewController` you will have

```
tableVC.myVC=self;
```

You will need to do this somewhere where you have a reference to your tableVC - so this could be in`prepareForSegue` if you are using storyboards and segues or wherever you present or push the table vc if you aren't

Comment: Thank you. I see the error of my ways. :) Got it working with prepareForSegue.